# MySQL constraints to force data check on two columns

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have this innoDB table with two columns in Mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  `id_1` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_2` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And I want to force a check on INSERT operations: id_1 must be less than id_2
So I tried with this but it didn't work out:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT mycheck CHECK (id_1 < id_2)
```

Is this even possible? What I did wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately MySQL don't support `CHECK CONSTRAINT` and thus your `ALTER` statement won't be of any use. Per MySQL documentation it parses but ignores the `CHECK` clause. Though you can get the similar effect using a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER`. Something like below

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER trig_check BEFORE INSERT ON  mytable 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF NEW.id_1 > NEW.id_2 THEN 
//Throw Error Probably 
END IF; 
END
//
delimiter ;
```